# what's the fastest way to remove duplicate lines from a file with billions of records in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have one CSV file with one column with billions of records, what's the fastest way to remove duplicate records from that file?

Comment: What's the average length of the lines?

Comment: Are duplicated records always adjacent or can they be anywhere in the file? If you're familiar with databases, I would be tempted to load the file into PostgreSQL or MySQL and do a SELECT UNIQUE query

Comment: By “duplicate” do you mean “repeaed” i.e. there may be more than two occurrences of the same value/record?

Comment: @bfris: since python comes with an in process database sqlite in the standard library, setting up a mysql or postgres database server and their respective drivers would seem overkill for this task.

Comment: `uniq file.csv > unique.csv`

Comment: @cricket_007 uniq only works to deduplicate a file if the data is already sorted.

Comment: @barny yes i mean exactly repeated, and yes there may be way more occurrence of the same record.

Comment: @bfris you mean to import CSV file to the database and sort it there? I need to mention taht CSV file belongs to big data (47 gigs)

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line. Create a hash of each line, if that hash  is in the set of previous hashes discard the line, otherwise add the hash to the set as well as storing the line to the output file.

Here is the code. It processes the input a line at a time, but needs to store a set of the hash values that will grow linearly with the number of unique lines:

```
import hashlib

with open('input_file') as ifile:
    with open('output_file', 'w') as ofile:
        seen = set()
        for line in ifile:
            hashval = int(hashlib.sha1(line.encode()).hexdigest(), 16)
            if hashval not in seen:
                seen.add(hashval)
                ofile.write(line)
```

**Alternative method:**

You could use [GZ-Sort](http://kmkeen.com/gz-sort/) to sort the huge file then easily remove any adjacent duplicated lines with the uniq command.

Answer (score 0):

Two approach I would consider:

1. If you can slurp the entire file into memory, just use a `set`.
2. Otherwise, if input file is larger than the memory you have available, create an sqlite database, setup a table with unique column constraint and insert the data into that table. Use executemany for best performance

Comment: Assuming you mean sqlite on disk, and not a memory table

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I meant on disk sqlite, which allows you to handle data much larger than available memory.

Comment: It is a big data file so it is hard to slurp 47 gigs